# Ubuntu doesn't reboot / shutdown properly

Tags: shutdown, reboot, acpi

```
root@pcu:~# uname -a
Linux pcu 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After any shutdown command (shutdown, halt, poweroff, init, GUI power buttons), PC immediately switches off. After reboot command, PC immediately goes to booting again.

Booting goes without any errors, notifications.

BIOS ACPI settings are usual. After reboot / power on, BIOS shortly beeps once.

Previous Ubuntu 12 installation worked fine at this hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by upgrading BIOS firmware and reinstalling Ubuntu ACPI subsystem, without any specials tweaks.

Now on poweroff / reboot I see fully shutdown log.